# Add SecurityTokenHandler to WCF programmatically

Tags: wcf, security, wif

I'm implementing custom UserNameSecurityTokenHandler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.usernamesecuritytokenhandler.aspx) and I plan to use it with my WCF service.

I have no issues registering it within web.config and it works flawlessly.

However due to requirements of the client, I'm supposed to move initialization of handler from Web.Config to code.

I've been looking for a way to implement UserNameSecurityTokenHandler somehow as IServiceBehavior, however without much success.

a) Is it doable at all?

b) How?

c) Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here 
http://leastprivilege.com/2012/07/16/wcf-and-identity-in-net-4-5-usernamepassword-authentication/

I added the token handler at service host creation time.